# How to hide refresh button and navigate button in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge

How to hide

Refresh button

navigate buttons

Profile Button

Bookmarks button

Other Bookmarks button

in Google Chrome and ms edge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the display of the relevant UI in the Appearance bar in the `settings` of these two browsers. For example, you can only hide the `bookmarks bar` and some other buttons in Google chrome. But regarding the refresh and navigation buttons you mentioned, they cannot be hidden because of UI design.

Maybe you can try to make suggestions to the relevant team, just press `shift + alt + I` to send your feedback.